# Parameters are empty although specified in url

Tags: spark-java

Using latest spark-core.
I am trying to setup a simple GET call.

`http://localhost:9346/update/?adasd=123`

I am have the following in my main method:

```java
get("/update/", (request, response) -> request.params().toString());
```

If I execute my call I get `{}`, so it appears as if the parameters are empty.
I also tried `/update/:adasd`.
This is my first look at spark-java, so I might be getting something basic wrong here.

I just want to be able to read the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up. You are passing queryParameters but trying to print pathParameters.

For this call:

```
http://localhost:9346/update?adasd=123
```

Code like this is required:

```
get("update", (request, response) -> request.queryParams());
```

A call to this endpoint will result in this output:

```
[adasd]
```